# If statement checks if argv is a number

Tags: c, if-statement, g++, argv

I have this `if` statement in my program that should check arguments entered when starting program. For example `./a.out 2 2 + 0 x` (if someone could write proper name in English for this type of entering arguments I would be grateful.

My `if` statement should check if entered argument is NOT a number:

```
if(atof(argv[cnt]) == 0 && argv[cnt] != "0")
```

but it is true when argb[cnt] = 0 which is unfortunate (checked with GDB)
What did I do wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: `argv[cnt] != "0"` is nonsense. You aren't checking its value at all. You can't compare strings this way in C. It compare *pointers* which will in this case always be different.

Comment: the arguments are an "arithmetic expression" or a "reverse polish notation" thereof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use in C [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) (or [strtod(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtod.3.html) for `double`-s) which manages the end pointer:

```
char* end = NULL;
long n = strtol(argv[cnt], 0, &end);
if (n > 0 && *end == '\0')
   printf("got a good number %ld\n", n);
```

You could also use [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) and `%n`. Notice it is returning a scanned item count:

```
int p= -1;
long n = 0;
if (sscanf(argv[cnt], "%ld %n", &n, &p) >= 1 && p>0)
  printf("got a good number %ld (and scanned %d bytes)", n, p);
```

BTW, if you need to compare strings, use [strcmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html). `argv[cnt] != "0"` is comparing *addresses* and I'm sure on your (or mine) system it would be always true (even for a `0`  program argument) since program arguments are in the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), but literal strings are in the [code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment).

If you are coding in [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) learn about [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) (its [operator ==](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) do what you imagine) and perhaps [std::istringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)

Don't forget to compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`).

<sup>PS. I hope you are on Linux, it is a very nice platform to learn programming.</sup>

Comment: Perhaps, upon failure attempting `strtod()` as OP said "number" and input may be ".1".